# How do I make a file template for PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'd like to have some boilerplate info about license, author, etc. at the top of every new file I create, but I can't find the correct boxes to tick.

Basically, I want to create a new file, and have it already populated (at the top) with

```
'''
   author: Me
   license: something
   copyright: something
'''
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 9):

Go to `Windows -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Templates`

Create a new template:

- Fill the name with `<Empty>`
- choose `Editor`
- enable `Automatically insert`
- Add a description (optionally)
- Copy your template in the pattern

  - you might want to use some variables like `${year}` and `${cursor}` at the end.

To add your template on the file:

Just press `Ctrl+Space` on an empty line or after a whitespace and select `<Empty>` and it should add your template on your file.

Note:
You can create as many `<Empty>` templates as you want, `<Empty>` templates won't show up when you've called the code completion after entering some letters.

Comment: Where can you find and edit these variables? E.g. ${user_email}?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Nothing is inserted when making a new .py file.

Comment: @tsbertalan - on the Eclipse help pages, there's a guide for General and Java-specific variables: see http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm ... as I understand it, adding your own variables is not super-hard, but I've never done that.