# Any way to have "Templates" view for PyDev in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, templates, pydev

Is there any way to have 'Templates' View panel for perspective/workspace?
I'm Talking about:

```
Windows -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Templates
```

Found nothing in preferences.

If it's not there, hope developer checks this tag and accepts feature requests from this board :) I think it would be nice to have panel of templates to look at, in addition to `Ctrl+Space` action.

1. Templates view with text search func.
2. Optional: Text search in Tasks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of "templates"? Are you doing Django or something?

Comment: ... or are you referring to code templates, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220295/10077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such view in PyDev right now.

The place to ask for such a request would be the tracker at

https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/

I'm focusing the requests to work on mostly through votes in the tracker now...

But if there's a pull request for that available, adding it could be done easily :)